# Spliting a string into two words using while

Tags: c#, .net, string, console-application

```
string givenstring,outputString="";
int i, j = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the string");
givenstring = Console.ReadLine();
i = (givenstring.Length) / 2;

while (j < i)
{
    outputString += givenstring[j];
    j++;
}

Console.WriteLine(outputString);
outputString = string.Empty;

while (i < givenstring.Length)
{
    outputString += givenstring[i];
    i++;
}
Console.WriteLine(outputString);
```

Here I split the string into two string.
For example, input:

> Helloworld

output:

> Hello world.

But now I need the output:

> dlrow olleH

Comment: Your first example only prints "Hello", not "Hello world".

Comment: What behavior do you expect for strings like "Hidoovde" or "Hellosir or for any other string which contains words of different length or more than 2 words etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx) like this:

```
string reversed = arr.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) => next + " " + workingSentence);
Console.WriteLine(reversed);
```

I just modify your code. It should be look like this now:

```
string givenstring, outputString = "";
int i, j = 0;
string[] arr = new string[2];
Console.WriteLine("Enter the string");
givenstring = Console.ReadLine();
i = (givenstring.Length) / 2;
while (j < i)
{
     outputString += givenstring[j];
     j++;
}
Console.Write("Input -> " + outputString + " ");//hello world
arr[0] = outputString;

outputString = string.Empty;
while (i < givenstring.Length)
{
    outputString += givenstring[i];
    i++;
}
arr[1] = outputString;

Console.WriteLine(outputString);
string reversed = arr.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) => next + " " + workingSentence);
Console.WriteLine("output -> " + reversed);//world hello
Console.WriteLine("output -> " + ReverseString(reversed));//olleh dlrow
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Edit**: As a better solution I removed redundant code. Check this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arr = new string[2];
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the string");
    var givenstring = Console.ReadLine();
    if (givenstring != null)
    {
       int i = (givenstring.Length) / 2;
       arr[0] = givenstring.Substring(0 , i);
       arr[1] = givenstring.Substring(i, givenstring.Length - i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Input -> " + arr[0] + " " + arr[1]);//hello world
    var reversed = arr.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) => next + " " + workingSentence);
    Console.WriteLine("output -> " + reversed);//world hello
    Console.WriteLine("output -> " + ReverseString(reversed));//olleh dlrow
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string ReverseString(string str)
{
     char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();
     char[] result = new char[chars.Length];

     for (int i = 0, j = str.Length - 1; i < str.Length; i++, j--)
     {
            result[i] = chars[j];
     }

     return new string(result);
}
```

Comment: @Parthiban ... Check my updated answer. I have removed redundant code and also changed to `Input -> Helloworld` and `output -> dlrow olleH`.

Comment: Send `reversed` to  `ReverseString` and final result will be:`output -> dlrow olleH`.

Answer (score 7):

The question is a *vague* one. If you need put all the *words* in the string in *reversed order*, e.g.

> "This is a test string" -> "String test a is this"

then you can do

```
  String source = "This is a test string";

  String result = String.Join(" ", source
    .Split(' ')
    .Reverse()
    .Select((item, index) => index > 0 ? item.ToLower() : ToNameCase(item)));

  // "String test a is this"
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

where `ToNameCase()` is something like this:

```
  private static String ToNameCase(String source) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
      return source;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source.Length);

    sb.Append(Char.ToUpper(source[0]));
    sb.Append(source.Substring(1));

    return sb.ToString();
  }
```

**Edit**: if you don't pay attention to *case*, i.e.

> "This is a test string" -> "string test a is This"

you can *simplify* the solution into just

```
  String source = "This is a test string";

  String result = String.Join(" ", source
    .Split(' ')
    .Reverse());

  // "string test a is This"
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Edit 2**: If you want to split the text into `range` chunks with *equal lengths* (with possible exception of the *last chunk*), and then *reverse* them:

```
  String source = "HelloWorld";
  int range = 2; // we want 2 chunks ("Hello" and "World")

  String result = String.Join(" ", Enumerable
    .Range(0, range)
    .Select(index => index == range - 1 ?
        source.Substring(source.Length / range * index) :
        source.Substring(source.Length / range * index, source.Length / range))
    .Reverse()); // remove ".Reverse()" and you will get "Hello World"

  // "World Hello"
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixture of `Skipwhile`, `Concat` and `Take` methods :

```
string s = "Helloworld";

int half = s.Length / 2;

s = new String(s.SkipWhile((ss, i) => i < half)
                .Concat(" ").Concat(s.Take(half)).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output : `world Hello`

OR you can simply concat substrings :

```
string givenstring,outputString="";
Console.WriteLine("Enter the string");
givenstring = Console.ReadLine();

int half = givenstring.Length / 2;

givenstring = givenstring.Substring(half , half) + " " + givenstring.Substring(0, half );
```

(I assume you've string with just two words because you didn't provide an example of a test string you work with other then Helloworld)...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string s = "Helloworld someother string";

var str = s.Split(' ')[0];
int i = str.Length/2;

Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(i) + "  " + str.Substring(0,i));
//or
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",str.Substring(i),str.Substring(0,i)));
```